# Having trouble with css and divs layout. Also what tools..?

Tags: css, layout, html

I've been trying to get a goal layout as pictured in the mockup below. I've been working on it for a couple of hours now and I just can't get it quite right. I'm working with Notepad++ which may not be the right tool for graphical layout stuff. This is just a one-off page for a webgame, with a single page and relatively simple layout (I think). (btw I added borders just to see the colors of each square, but they're not needed in the final result)

Here's what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/2kLSV/

Maybe I'm using too many nested divs or something..

```
<div class="infos">
            <div class="infos-players">

                <div class="infos-players-name">
                    <div class="icon-cross"></div>
                    <div id="player1-name">Player 1</div>
                    <div id="player1-arrow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="infos-players-score" id="player1-score">101</div>

                <div class="infos-players-name">
                    <div class="icon-naught"></div>
                    <div id="player2-name">Player 2</div>
                    <div id="player2-arrow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="infos-players-score" id="player2-score">202</div>

            </div>
            <div class="infos-round">Round
                <br />123</div>
        </div>
```

This is a mock-up of the expected result
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this, should be a little more like what you want. I tweaked a little CSS and added a clear fix to get the orange border to contain everything properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/2kLSV/1/

```
<div id="page">
        <h1>Four in a row</h1>

    <div id="game-zone">
        <div class="cf" id="board">
            <div class="loading">Loading...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="infos">
            <div class="infos-players">

                <div class="infos-players-name">
                    <div class="icon-cross"></div>
                    <div id="player1-name">Player 1</div>
                    <div id="player1-arrow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="infos-players-score" id="player1-score">101</div>

                <div class="infos-players-name">
                    <div class="icon-naught"></div>
                    <div id="player2-name">Player 2</div>
                    <div id="player2-arrow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="infos-players-score" id="player2-score">202</div>

            </div>
            <div class="infos-round">Round
                <br />123</div>
            <br style="clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code it's working for me

[picture demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-HhAFfhRAowTEY5SkRabmVVRWdKd1d6LTBxTVF6UjNTdlF3/edit?usp=sharing)

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
        <h1>Four in a row</h1>

    <div id="game-zone">
        <div class="cf" id="board">
            <div class="loading">Loading...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="infos">
            <div class="infos-players">

                <div class="infos-players-name">
                    <div class="icon-cross"></div>
                    <div id="player1-name">Player 1</div>
                    <div id="player1-arrow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="infos-players-score" id="player1-score">101</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="infos-players-name">
                    <div class="icon-naught"></div>
                    <div id="player2-name">Player 2</div>
                    <div id="player2-arrow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="infos-players-score" id="player2-score">202</div>

            </div>
            <div class="infos-round">Round
                <br />123</div>
        </div>

        <div id="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
/* infos */
.infos:after
{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.infos {

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;

    font: bold 1em'uni', Arial, sans-serif;

    background-color: #f80;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.infos-players {

    float: left;

    width: 70%;

    background-color: #ff0;

    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
}

.infos-players-name {

    float: left;

    width: 40%;

    background-color: #f00;

    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1
        margin-bottom:5px;
}

.infos-players-score {

    float: right;

    width: 40%;

    background-color: #0f0;

    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.infos-round {

    float: left;

    text-align: center;

    width: 25%;

    background-color: #08F;
    margin-left:3px;
    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
}

.icon-cross {

    float: left;

    background-image: url("../images/icons.png");

    background-size: 500% 100%;

    background-position: 0 0;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 1.5em;

    height: 1.5em;

}

.icon-naught {

    float: left;

    background-image: url("../images/icons.png");

    background-size: 500% 100%;

    background-position: 25% 0;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 1.5em;

    height: 1.5em;

}

.icon-starwin {

    float: right;

    background-image: url("../images/icons.png");

    background-size: 500% 100%;

    background-position: 50% 0;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 1.5em;

    height: 1.5em;

}

.icon-starempty {

    float: right;

    background-image: url("../images/icons.png");

    background-size: 500% 100%;

    background-position: 75% 0;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 1.5em;

    height: 1.5em;

}

.icon-arrow {

    float: left;

    background-image: url("../images/icons.png");

    background-size: 500% 100%;

    background-position: 100% 0;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 1.5em;

    height: 1.5em;

}
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
```